# Category of symmetric monoidal functors out of a symmetric monoidal category with duals form a groupoud

Tags: category-theory, dual-spaces, monoidal-categories, higher-category-theory

In Lurie's proof of the cobordism hypothesis, he uses the following fact:

Let $C,D$ be a symmetric monoidal categories with duals, and $Z_1,Z_2\colon C\to D$ be symmetric monoidal functors, then any natrual transformation $\alpha\colon Z_1\to Z_2$ is invertible with inverse given by
$$
Z_2\left(M\right)\xrightarrow{\sim}Z_2\left(M^*\right)^*\xrightarrow{\alpha_{M*}^*}Z_1\left(M^*\right)^*\xrightarrow{\sim}Z_1\left(M\right)
$$
I don't quite see why this is the inverse.

Comment: $\alpha$ has to be a *monoidal* transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Theorem 3.2 in *[Duals Invert](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-009-9210-7)* by Franco, Street, Wood.